# Why when sending a post request to the API, i'm getting a response of an empty array?

Tags: angular, typescript

I want to send data to an API, using a post method, i've put the data in an object just like the server seem to ask, but when posting the object to the API, i'm getting a response of 200, but also an empty array. According to the API, should i be getting a response just like the "Response samples"(From the print Screen?).

The service where i do the post request:

```html
  voteGame(vote:vote) {
    const body = vote;
    return this.http.post<vote>('https://api-labs.tindin.com.br/games/rate', body).subscribe(data => console.log(data));
  }
```

The model i've created for the object:

```html
  export interface vote {
    gameId: string;
    rate: number;
  }
```

and the function that calls for the service:

```html
  voteGame(vote: number) {
    const voteObj = {
      gameId: this.gameId,
      rate: vote,
    };
    console.log(voteObj);
    this.voteGameService.voteGame(voteObj);
  }
```

[image: Picture of the doc of the API]

Comment: this API is broken you can try to call:
curl --request POST \
  --url https://api-labs.tindin.com.br/games/rate \
  --header 'Content-Type: application/json' \
  --data '{
 "gameId": "62b5dc2f155a1e6b4f9cd1ae",
 "rate": 2
}'
 and see that it returns response first time and after that returns an empty object if you call it with same "rate"

Comment: @izmaylovdev wanna submit that as an answer so you can get the rep points?

Answer (score 0):

If my understanding is correct, you want to retrieve response from REST endpoint, and use it in your application.

First you can create a type for the response of REST endpoint :

```js
export type VoteGameResponse {
  game: string;
  totalVotes: number;
  ...   
}
```

Then, method to post new vote should just return `Observable` from `HttpClient` :

```js
export class VoteGameService { 
  voteGame(vote: Vote): Observable<VoteGameResponse> {
    return this.http.post<Vote>('...', vote);
  }
}
```

Then, app can request a new vote by subscribing to observable and use the response to update view for example :

```js
  voteGame(vote: number) {
    this.voteGameService.voteGame({
      gameId: this.gameId,
      rate: vote,
    }).subscribe(response => {
      this.totalVotes = response.totalVotes;
      //... or everything wanted to update view
    })
  }
```